# Customize input box and button width inside input group in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a search box like that

[image]

**Code**

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input name="search" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" >
     <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="icon-search"></span></button>
     </span>
</div>
```

Here search box is 100%.

I want to customize search box and search button size 80% and 20%

actually I want to make my search box like that 
[image]

Any Idia?

Comment: Yes. I have an idea. Use CSS.

Comment: Do  you know any HTML and CSS?

Comment: I think you need to: (1) change `icon-search` CSS to point to your image, (2) add a class to your input to fix height and increase border-radius. As John said is all CSS

Answer (score 3):

Pure CSS.

```css
#search-form .form-control,
#search-form .form-control:focus,
#search-form .form-control:hover {
  height: 50px;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  left: 20px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
/**/

#search-form button.btn.btn-orange,
#search-form button.btn.btn-orange:hover,
#search-form button.btn.btn-orange:focus {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 175px;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}
#search-form button.btn.btn-orange:before,
#search-form button.btn.btn-orange:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 55%;
  background: #DC521F;
  z-index: -1;
}
#search-form button.btn.btn-orange:before {
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-right: none;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
#search-form button.btn.btn-orange:after {
  right: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<form id="search-form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-orange" type="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                    </span>

      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>
```

Comment: almost everything is fine but 1 small problem.when hover the search button it works fine otherwise it look like rectangle. see the output in my project http://imgur.com/JVO0HDX. But when I hover my mouse on search button it looks ok.

Comment: when I copy and paste in a blank page it works fine. but in my porject it not work properly. I dont know where I do the mistake :(

Comment: You're probably just seeing some CSS conflicts: try adding a unique class or ID to the search form. See updated example

Answer (score 2):

I've made you a fiddle. You may have to adjust some things but you got the idea, right?

My advice. Start learning CSS. I helped you now. But no one is going to do your job for you.

Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nfnbow3u/2/).

The code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="input-group">
     <input name="search" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" >
     <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"></button>
     </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.input-group-btn img{
    width: 16px;
}
.form-control{
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius:20px;
}
.btn{
    background: url('http://s17.postimg.org/m8q2d6r9n/o_P5_Lw.png') no-repeat;
    height: 42px;
    width: 115px;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using pure CSS method.

Your HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input name="search" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" >
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <span id="triangle-down"></span> <!-- <<<<< ADD THIS TO YOUR HTML -->
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="icon-search"></span></button>
     </span>
</div>
```

Within your CSS you can do this:

```
.input-group{
  width:60%;
  margin:20px;
}
.form-control{
  border-radius:20px;
  width:80%;
}
.input-group-btn{
  width:20%;
}
.btn-default{
  border-radius:20px;
  background-color:#DC521F;
  color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
#triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left:-20px;
  top:1px;
  z-index:100;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 32px solid #DC521F;
}
```

A WORKING DEMO HERE: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avdxwM)

**-------UPDATE-------**

If you add this to the CSS:

```
.hover{
  border-top: 32px solid #E6E6E6 !important;
}
```

and use this as JS code:

```
$( ".input-group-btn" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( '.triangle-down').addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( '.triangle-down' ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

then the HOVER will works like you want it.

A WORKING DEMO HERE: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avdxwM)

Comment: when I hover mouse on search box design changed. Can you please have look in you codepen output.

Comment: You can do this by adding some JS code. See my modified answer.@NurUddin